# Bypass URL encoding(client side) to perform XSS

Tags: javascript, security, browser, xss, url-encoding

I'm learning about XSS attacks and methods of prevention. Right now i'm figuring out about XSS(DOM).

As you may know most browsers encode contents that is taken from the URL to prevent javascript injections. It ignores symbols such as <./ . 
I read to bypass that kind of protection double encoding can be used.

Example of using double encoding:

> www.xss/com/default=123%253Cscript%253Ealert('XSS')%253C%252Fscript%253E

It did not give me any positive result.

What would you suggest or how would you exploit below url ?

> www.xss/com/ www.xss.com/default=123

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:
www.xss.com/example1.php?name=alert('XSS Found');

www.xss.com/example1.php?id'=alert('XSS Found');

It can be name, id.. Does not matter.

Also you can find xss payloads and use them in BURP. Just download the payloads file and then make request with BURP. Send the request to intruder and select the payload file. After all start the attack.